# My android app can't login to facebook account after release?

Tags: android

My android app can't login to facebook account after i signed it, although i used the keystore also to the hashkey before setting in facebook app

this is the console:

> C:\Users\omya>keytool -exportcert -alias aliase_name -keystore e:\my-release-key.keystore | "c:\openssl\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "c:\openssl\bin\openssl"  base64
>
> Enter keystore password:  keystorepass
>
> JEkWPfnZGYCQL1BEVhCmdF9+K80=

although i can login in case of using debugkey

where's the problem??

Comment: Without code or build process description or a possible error message, we are clueless like you. How about the response from facebook that you receive on failed login? Maybe you switch seats to read your question, you should see that you don't even try to provide some information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by using java 1.6 instead of 1.7